# Portlet Development with Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, portlet, liferay-ide

I'm starting to learn some portlet development. I'm wondering if there are any good (preferably recent since many of the guides I saw date back a few years) Hello Portlet or beginners guides. I have eclipse set up but I'm not sure what plugins/libraries/etc I need to start developing portlets for a Tomcat server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why dont you use liferay portal server if you want portlets? what are you going to host portlets on - you need a portlet container in addition to tomatc

Comment: I did a little more research and you're right, I'm going to need a portlet container. Can I install liferay on top of my existing tomcat?

Comment: liferay runs with an inbuilt tomcat - so you essentially get the same. just dwonload and run the latest liferay portal

Comment: The thing is I'm need to install liferay on top of an existing tomcat that we configured and customized. But I found instructions to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay Portal (open source portal) has a set of eclipse plugins called [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE).  If you set it up and also setup a Liferay Plugin SDK (zip download), then use the New Liferay Project wizard after installing the Liferay IDE plugins you will have everything you need.  You can see the [Liferay IDE Getting Started guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial) for how to deploy your first portlet to Liferay.